# ConstraintLayout constraints are too wide

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to get more used to ConstraintLayout to see how useful it can be to avoid nesting views. I have two LinearLayouts below a FrameLayout that are constrained to the top/bottom of each other, like this:

[image]

I constrained these two (with the second constrained to the parent bottom) so that the landscape layout would adjust accordingly. However, the gap between these linearlayouts is too wide, since it's spread out over the entire vertical view. Is there a way I can shorten this gap while avoiding nesting them into a parent LinearLayout?

My XML:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dropbox_upload_btn"
        android:layout_width="306dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/box_upload_btn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageFrameLayout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.22">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/dropbox_android"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.35"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/dropbox_upload"
            android:layout_weight="2.43"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/box_upload_btn"
        android:layout_width="306dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dropbox_upload_btn"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.076">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/box_logo"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.35"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/box_upload"
            android:layout_weight="2.43"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove these lines.

`app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/box_upload_btn"`
`app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dropbox_upload_btn"`

and then try reducing the margin.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have those two views in a vertical chain. The default for this configuration is a chain style of `CHAIN_SPREAD` which will give you the gaps. Add the following to the top view of the chain.

```
layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="CHAIN_PACKED"
```

You can then control the spacing with margins or, maybe, vertical bias.

I hope this helps.